# PERL: line by line text parsing script

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

for excercise and curiosity, anyone knows if the following script can be made more compact and expedite:

```
foreach(@list){
    if ($_=~"givenName: ") {
        $cname=$_;
        $cname=~ s/givenName: //g;
    } 
    if ($_=~"cn: ") {
        $cn=$_;
        $cn=~ s/cn: //g;
    }
    ...
}
```

What is does:
- It looks for a string inside the line, to see if it contains that particular index
- It then strips off the string and read the rest of the line putting the content into the variable.
- This script reads line by line the result of another script and identify the fields of each line putting the value inside the proper variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about something like this?

```
my $data = {}; #a hashref to store your data
foreach my $line(@list){
    $line =~ s/(givenName|cn|more|names):\s//g and $data->{$1} = $line;
    ...
}
#EDIT: now you have all your data inside the hashref and can call each var accordingly
print $data->{givenName};
print $data->{cn};
```

Comment: @qwrrty: thank you but I need to be able to idenfity what data is inside the line, and then fill the variable with the left of the line: i.e.: name: John, address: cavendish str, tel: 0207 123 4556. Not all fields might be there, and not in the same order.

Comment: @user3008283 see my edit. It's easy to get any variable from the hash.

Comment: @user3008283 Do you mean that a single line may include several different variables that need to be parsed separately?

Comment: no, each line will only have 1 type of data, identified by the first word in the line: 
name: john
lastname: smith
etc
but the sequence will change, so the script needs to read the first part of the line to undertand what value will follow.

Comment: foibs, it look like your solution is doing exactly what I need. 
I like your code and the way you are using the hash.
My code does a similar way but I was curious to find a more elegant way to do it and yours does it.
Great Job

Answer (score 5):

If every line in the list is guaranteed to be in the format 'variableName: someText' then you could do this instead:

```
foreach (@list) {
    /^(\w+): (.*)/ && $vars{$1} = $2;
}
```

It's not exactly like your solution -- it puts the results into a `%vars` hash instead of into variables named `$cname`, `$cn`, etc. -- but it's more succinct and general.

Comment: Thank you qwrt. But the point is the lines are expected to be in any order. So the script needs to read the line to understand what var is reading.

Comment: This code will work regardless of which lines and variables appear first. If the "givenName" line appears first, then `$vars{givenName}` will be the first variable set. If "tel" appears first, then `$vars{tel}` will be the first variable set.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @list = ('name', 'givenName: ', 'noname');
foreach(@list){
    s/givenName: //g if /givenName: /; 
    my $var = $_;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you FlyingFrog, but can i also populate the variable within the same line? i.e.: $givenname=...if , $name=...if, $cn=...if

Comment: @user3008283 - see update - why do you want it on the same line?

Comment: ok with the update, I was just curious if it could be done in 1 line...that was part of the excercise :-). BTW, being done in the same line would also be part of the if. So that the variable is updated only if the string is matched.